# Why does my bubble sort not work in C

Tags: c

I am new on this site and self-learning how to program in C. The following code compiles without warning or error and executes, but the second print run is exactly the same as the first, i.e. my bubble sort routine does not work. A similar version of this using just single letter characters worked just fine. Any pointers (ahem...) would be appreciated as to where I am going wrong - thanks!

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{

    char * names[10] = {"Dave","Al","Roger","Gary","Marc","Tim","Bob","Cal","Sid","Joe"};

    int beginning;
    int end;
    int didSwap;
    char * temp = "This will be used to store names temporarily";
    int ctr;

    puts("\nHere are some random names:");
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
    {   
        printf("%s\n", names[ctr]);
    }

    for (beginning = 0; beginning < 9; beginning++)
    {
        didSwap = 0;
        for (end = beginning; end < 10; end++)
        {
            if (names[end] < names[beginning])
            {
                temp = names[end];
                names[end] = names[beginning];
                names[beginning] = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
            }
        }
        if (didSwap == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
    }

    puts("\nHere are the random names now in alphabetical order:");
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
    {   
        printf("%s\n", names[ctr]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you done?

Comment: Use `strcmp` instead of `<` for strings.

Comment: None, as no errors or warnings show up and I'm otherwise stumped. I've tried re-writing in many different ways (which does generate warnings), with no luck...

Comment: See [DEMO using strcmp](http://ideone.com/Kqlyhl)

Comment: Thank you BLUEPIXY, that was very helpful and now it works beautifully. Cheers, Marc

Comment: @MarcBolda I'd like to point out that you don't need errors to necessitate debugging. Debugging is often just looking for where data becomes wrong. If a function is giving back bad data, it must be *becoming* bad somewhere in the function. To solve it, you'd go through the function line by line to find where the mistake is. That's debugging. It's one of the most important skills a programmer can have. I recommend practicing debugging whenever possible.

Comment: I wouldn't ever learn to write bubble sort at all because there are better sorting algorithms that are as easy to write correctly.

Comment: Thanks Carcigenicate - your point is well taken, and that's why I'm writing these short programs by myself, to get lots of practice with this. I wasn't aware of the strcmp function - but I am now. I've only been at this a relatively short time but each day i am learning more. This site is a great resource.

Comment: Thanks Antti, I've heard this from others as well - but it was a starting point for me and I will be moving on to others now as I go forward.

Answer (score 3):

You can't usefully compare strings with `<`; you should normally use the `strcmp` function instead (unless you need case-insensitive sorting, …).  In C, those strings are memory addresses, so you are sorting by the address of the string and not its value.

Comment: Yes, I'm learning more and more about strings - thanks for your input.